# "Skipping non-existent input file" error using solc docker on Windows

Tags: solc, windows, docker

I'm trying to setup a local build environment for Solidity on Windows (10).

One of the options recommended in the Solidity docs is docker.

Superficially, the docker image runs fine:

```
C:\work\eth>docker run ethereum/solc:stable --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.Linux.g++
```

But, it's not managing to access any files

```
C:\work\eth>docker run ethereum/solc:stable Coin.sol
Skipping non-existent input file ""Coin.sol""

C:\work\eth>dir Coin.sol

 Directory of C:\work\eth

05/22/2017  02:55 PM               873 Coin.sol
               1 File(s)            873 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  263,229,722,624 bytes free
```

Is this a docker issue? An issue with the solc image? How should I proceed?

Comment: I have the same issue trying to execute solc from a maven plugin within Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Docker isn't aware of your local file system by default.
You need to bind your local directory as a data volume. 
(https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

In your case, I believe the command you're looking for is:

```
docker run -v c:\work\eth:c:\solidity ethereum/solc:stable Coin.sol
```

If you want to check if docker can see your local file, these two commands should help:

```
docker run --entrypoint /bin/pwd -v c:\work\eth:c:\solidity ethereum/solc:stable

docker run --entrypoint /bin/ls -v c:\work\eth:c:\solidity ethereum/solc:stable
```

(I'm not a windows user and have not tested these on windows)